# openweathermap flutter call for local condtions. I get error type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: string, dynamic

void getData() async {
http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$latitude&lon=$longitude&appid=$apiKey'));

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  String data = response.body;
  var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);

  String city = jsonDecode(decodedData)['name'];
  double temperature = jsonDecode(decodedData)['main']['temp'];
  int condition = jsonDecode(decodedData)['weather'][0]['id'];

  print(city);
  print(temperature);
  print(condition);
} else {
  print(response.statusCode);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was using code from a tutorial that was about a year old. I followed  the flutter docs to solve this problem by creating a WeatherData class with the city, temperature and condition properties and called
the http request through the WeatherData class. It worked without errors

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The main issue was that “String city” should have been declared “var city”